# D3 Colors d3.interpolate

Tags: d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to set 0 values on my c3.js graph to white instead of the default grey value.

I am using

`colors: d3.interpolateHslLong(d3.hsl(250, 1, 0.5), d3.hsl(0, 1, 0.5))` currently.

Does anyone know how to define the 0 value color? It seems no matter what I set the min and max values to, 0 remains grey.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

White has 'lightness' equal to 1 (or 100%)

So, the first value will need have: d3.hsl(250, 1, **1**), eg

```
d3.interpolateHslLong(d3.hsl(250, 1, 1), d3.hsl(0, 1, 0.5))
```

The hue and saturation (the first two values in the HSL constructor) can be anything, but they will affect the colour gradient to the second colour.